# Pdf and Mgf of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables that follow an exponential distribution with mean $1$ and let $W = Y - X$.

(i) Using the cumulative distribution function (cdf), find the probability density function (pdf) of $W$, $f_W(w)$ for $w > 0$. (No need to compute $w \leq 0$).

(ii) Determine the moment generating function (mgf) of $W$ by finding the mgfs of $Y$ and $-X$. Justify where the mgf is defined.

I'm not quite sure how to do this problem but here is what I did:

(i)

Suppose $X, Y$ have means $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. If $W = Y - X$ then (I think)

$$P(W \leq w) = \int_0^\infty \int_{0}^{x+z} \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x} \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 y}\,dy \ \ dx$$

If we substitute $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 1$ then

$$P(W \leq w) = \int_0^\infty \int_{0}^{x+z} e^{-x - y}\,dy \ \ dx$$

(ii)

The moment generating function for an exponential distribution is $M(t) = \frac{1}{1- \theta t}$ where $\theta > 0$ and $t < \frac{1}{\theta}$.

If the mean $\theta = 1$ then we know that for $Y$

$M_Y(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$

As for $-X$, I'm not sure.

I'm not sure about the formula in (i) or how to derive it, and I'm confused on finding the mgf of $-X$ in (ii). But in any case I am stuck. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the formula in (i),
$$ \mathbb{P}(W \leq w) = \mathbb{P}(f(X,Y) \in ]-\infty,w]) = \mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in f^{-1}(]-\infty,w]))$$
where $f(x,y) = y-x$. Since $X \sim \mathcal{E}(\lambda_1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{E}(\lambda_2)$ are independent and admit both density, denoted $f_X$ and $f_Y$, the couple $(X,Y)$ admites the density
$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ and thus
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in f^{-1}(]-\infty,w])) &= \int_{f^{-1}(]-\infty,w])} \lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2y}1_{x >0}1_{y>0}dxdy\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} 1_{y-x \leq w} \lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2y}1_{x >0}1_{y>0}dxdy\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} 1_{y \leq x+w}\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2y}dxdy \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} 1_{y \leq x+w}\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2y}dydx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} 1_{y \leq x+w}1_{x+w \geq 0}\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2y}dydx \\
\end{align}
and now you can adapt the rest of the computations depending on the sign of $w$.

For (ii), for all $t \in ]-1,1[$,
$$ M_{-X}(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}] = M_X(-t) = \frac{1}{1+t}.$$

Comment: Unfortunately, I am relatively new to distributions and thus not familiar with these theorems..

Comment: Which part are you unfamiliar with?

Comment: Part (i). I have no idea what Lebesgue measures are or the Fubini-Tonelli theorem etc. I don't think I am supposed to use these for this problem.

Comment: Ok let me rewrite this into a probabilistic language

Comment: I think you cannot avoid Fubini's theorem to do this kind of computation right (I used them twice without mentioning), so either you use them as a dark tool, either you learn them.

Comment: For (ii), would the following be correct then: $M_{Z}(t)=M_{Y-X}(t) = E\left(e^{(Y-X)t}\right) = E \left( e^{Yt}e^{-Xt} \right) = E\left(e^{Yt}\right)E\left(e^{-Xt}\right)=M_{Y}(t)E\left(e^{X(-t)}\right)=M_{Y}(t)M_{X}(-t)= \frac{1}{1-t} \cdot \frac{1}{1+t} = \frac{1}{1-t^2}$.

Comment: Yes it is, note that the fourth equality holds because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: That is what I thought. Also, where is this mgf defined?

Comment: Where does your computations are valid?

Comment: Is it $0 < t < 1$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121011/discussion-between-blamethelag-and-turnipsavocados).